# why does drush tag 8.0.0-beta14 returns all zero for config core.extensions

Tags: drush, 8, configuration

After a fresh install of d8 with several core modules activated (block, breakpoint, database logging, field, filter, internal page cache, node, system, toolbar, update manager, user, views, views ui), extracting the config indicates that all the above are off:

```
# drush8 @myproject.dev config-get core.extension
module:
  block: 0
  breakpoint: 0
  config: 0
  datetime: 0
  dblog: 0
  entity_reference: 0
  field: 0
  file: 0
  filter: 0
  image: 0
  node: 0
  page_cache: 0
  system: 0
  text: 0
  toolbar: 0
  update: 0
  user: 0
  views: 0
  views_ui: 0
  minimal: 1000
theme:
  stark: 0
  classy: 0
  seven: 0
```

`stark` is, in fact, the default activated theme and `seven` is the admin theme.

The plan is to dump the config from the dev server and then import it into the stage server; but this is tricky if the config dump from dev is "blank."

Is this what's supposed to happen?

I'm using drupal version 8.0.0-beta12, and drush version 8.0.0-beta14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numeric values in core.extension are the module weight; if a module is disabled, then it does not appear in the list at all.

Comment: Obvious in hindsight. Where are the config YAML documented?

Comment: Good question! I tried to find documentation when I answered the question, but could not find anything.  We have this page: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!config!install!core.extension.yml/8, but it is not super useful. Usually, the change records (https://www.drupal.org/list-changes/published/drupal) are a good place to check, but I didn't find anything there either.